# Eclipse RCP writing to console overhead

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have Eclipse RCP application without console. But in my source code for this app a lot of information is written to the console. My question is: will this situation costs me overhead or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a console View, then it might cause some problems. For instance, in current project, we were also using console frequently, to output some debugging messages. At some point the bug was raised by the client, that application has crashed (or was unresponsive any more, I don't remember exactly). After digging it up, we have found, that we have run out of threads because of the console and we had to switch it off.

Comment: yes, I mean a Console View. If there is no Console View in app, but app writes a lot of information to it, will it cost me some overhead or not?

Comment: As I have mentioned before. We have run out of threads, but it is because we were creating a new Job to write into the console. If it is also your case, then you may also get this problem too. If you just print into the console, then you are most likely on the safe side.